# AJAX request not working on localhost CORS policy

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, angular9

I am creating an angular application which involves working with API. I have created an API on my localhost and tried to request on it with AJAX. But it shows me the CORS error. I tried everything to solve this but nothing worked even from the stackoverflow. It shows me error like

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost/graphql' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**How can I do this?**

Comment: Please show the error

Comment: Did you added browser CORS extension ?

Comment: @JaydipJadhav I don't know

Comment: You wrote that you tried everything - did you try adding a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the API response, as the error message tells you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the same origin. The site is at `http://localhost:4200` but you are trying to access `http://localhost`.

Add the port so that they both match, e.g. send your request to `http://localhost:4200/graphql`

Alternatively, add some CORS headers on your server.

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200`

You can do this in Express with the `cors` middleware
If you are on express server just add the following line:

```js
const cors = require("cors")  // npm i cors
app.use(cors())
```

Read more about CORS [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: but on this port my angular app runs and my API & app both are clashing

Comment: Are you using `ng serve`?

Comment: I understood what are you saying but how can I add cors. Can you add the xhr request code please!

Comment: @YogeshDeveloper CORS must be added on the server.

Comment: Yes. to serve my application

Comment: Please tell me how can I do this in my local express server?

Comment: @YogeshDeveloper this is the development server. You can run your API and serve your Angular from the same server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208899/discussion-between-yogesh-developer-and-codebling).